# Parse XML Feed to Display Images for Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, slider, nivo-slider

I'm working with my boss and trying to make a slideshow that is very easy for him to update.  XML seems to be the perfect implementation.  What I've done is create an XML file that will be parsed by jQuery into the #slider div.  Then Nivo will pick up those images and display them.  However, it seems that NivoSlider loads before the actual parsing is done so Nivo doesn't detect those images (even though using Firebug you can tell that they are there).  Is there any way to delay loading NivoSlider until this information has been parsed?  Before I started fixing this bug 50% of the time Nivo would detect the images and then the other half it wouldn't...  You can see what's going on here: http://snowtailcreative.com/domains/portfolio/xml/

XML:

```
<news>
    <entry>
        <slider>true</slider>
        <title>Computer Science Wins Again</title>
        <department>Computer Sience</department>
        <image>images/up.jpg</image>
        <link>http://www.google.com</link>
    </entry>
</news>
```

JavaScript:

```
// XML Parser
function parseXML() {

    // Get XML File
    $.get('example.xml', function(xml){

        // Loop Through Each Entry in XML
        $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){

            // Declare Variables
            var entry = $(this);
            var type = entry.find('slider').text();
            var title = entry.find('title').text();
            var department = entry.find('department').text();
            var image = entry.find('image').text();
            var link = entry.find('link').text();

            // Sort Through Item Types
            if(type == 'true'){
                var slider = '<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + image + '" title="' + title + '" alt="' + department + '" /></a>';
            }
            if(type == 'false'){
                var archive = '<h2>' + department + '</h2><p>' + title + '</p><a href="' + link + '">Read More</a>';
            }

            // Append Data
            $("#archive").append(archive);
            $("#slider").prepend(slider);

        });

    });

}

$.when( parseXML() ).done(function(){
         $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
```

Comment: You would rather use JSON for a task like this: a) the file is smaller b) the JSON JavaScript parser is faster c) there are more examples for that use case.

Comment: Even so, my experience is that JSON is harder to read than XML.  So the decision is based on syntax as well.... but even with JSON, if NivoSlider still loads first, I would still have the same problem.